# How do you create a document with three columns and lines in between each column?

Tags: rules, columns

at the moment I have two column landscape:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and set `\columnseprule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```